# subtracting a values in table per tr

Tags: jquery

I don't know how to subtract a value in a table per row.
what I want to subtract and if the difference is zero that tr will be disabled when the date-time and guard change else append another tr until the difference is zero
the minuend is the Quantity,
the subtrahend is the Exit Item Qty, and
the difference is shown in the balance Qty.

below is the code:

```js
$('#Table_2 tbody tr ').each(function(){

    var row = $('#Table_2 tbody tr ')
    var quantity = $(row).find('input[data-column=" ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq "]').val() ;
    var exititem = $(row).find('input[data-column=" ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j "]').val();
    var minus = quantity - exititem; 
    $(row).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]').val(minus);
    
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-auto fs-11 ctrl-table3" contenteditable="false" name="ctrl_Table3_wukpm" id="Table_2">
    <thead class="bg-light">
        <tr><td>Items</td><td>Quantity</td><td>Exit Item Qty</td><td>Balance Qty</td><td>Guard On Duty</td><td>Date and Time</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="4" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
    </td>
</tr>
    <tr>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="4" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
    </td>
    </tr> <tr>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="4" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
    </td>
    </tr> <tr>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="5" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
        <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
    </td>
    <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
        <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
    </td>
    </tr> </tbody>
    <tfoot style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="99" class="text-right">
                <a class="fas fa-plus text-success" onclick="Templates.Table3.AddRow(this)"></a>
                <a class="fas fa-cog tbl3-group-editor" onclick="Templates.Table3.Edit(this)" style=""></a>
                <a class="fas fa-trash-alt tbl3-group-editor" style=""></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: `var row = $('#Table_2 tbody tr ')` -> `var row = $(this)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always while calculating in JS keep use the data types otherwise it will not calculate what you want.

```
parseFloat() parseInt()
```

Here you missed `var row = $(this)` in this line.
Code snippet below try once.

```js
$(document).on('input', '#Table_2 tbody tr input', function (event) {
    $('#Table_2 tbody tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this)
        var quantity = parseFloat($(row).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq"]').val() || 0);
        var exititem = parseFloat($(row).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j"]').val() || 0);
        var minus = quantity - exititem;
        $(row).find('input[data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc"]').val(minus);
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-sm table-bordered w-auto fs-11 ctrl-table3" contenteditable="false" name="ctrl_Table3_wukpm"
    id="Table_2">
    <thead class="bg-light">
        <tr>
            <td>Items</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Exit Item Qty</td>
            <td>Balance Qty</td>
            <td>Guard On Duty</td>
            <td>Date and Time</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai"
                    class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="4" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q"
                    class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" readonly>
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
                <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
                <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext "
                    placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="text" value="" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_d20ai"
                    class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_ft3p0" title="Items" readonly="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="4" data-ref="ctrl_Table3Column_td79q"
                    class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext text-muted" placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_evxcq" title="Quantity" readonly="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_9zd2j" title="Exit Item Qty" required="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:auto;">
                <input type="number" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_0opcc" title="Balance Qty" readonly>
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
                <input type="text" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext " placeholder=""
                    data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_zmlc9" title="Guard On Duty" required="">
            </td>
            <td class="p-0 " style="width:null;">
                <input type="datetime-local" value="" class="px-1 form-control-sm form-control-plaintext "
                    placeholder="" data-column="ctrl_Table3Column_8fa36" title="Date and Time" required="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot style="display: none;">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="99" class="text-right">
                <a class="fas fa-plus text-success" onclick="Templates.Table3.AddRow(this)"></a>
                <a class="fas fa-cog tbl3-group-editor" onclick="Templates.Table3.Edit(this)" style=""></a>
                <a class="fas fa-trash-alt tbl3-group-editor" style=""></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thank for answering my question, my last question what is the difference between parsefloat and parseint

Comment: JavaScript does not have the distinction of "floating point numbers" and "integers" on the language level. parseInt() and parseFloat() 
only differ in their parsing behavior, but not necessarily their return values. For example, parseInt("42") and parseFloat("42") 
would return the same value: a Number 42. [Read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)